# Physical meaning of some values

Tags: optics, waves, differential-equations

I'm working with the paraxial wave equation $$2ik_0\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0,\,-\infty<x<\infty,\,-\infty<y<\infty,\,z\geq 0,$$ where $k_0=\omega/c$, is the wave vector, with $\omega$ and $c$ being the monochromatic wave frequency and the speed of light in vacuum, respectively. I have the initial condition $$u(x,y,0)=u_0(x,y)=A exp(-(x^2+y^2)/w_0^2).$$ So i ended up with the solution $$u(x,y,z)=\frac{Ak_0w_0^2}{2iz+k_0w_0^2}exp\left(-k_0\frac{x^2+y^2}{2iz+k_0w_0^2}\right)$$.I computed the power of the laser beam $$P=\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|u(x,y,z)|^2dxdy=\frac{A^2w_0^2\pi}{2}.$$ Now im asked to find the explicit expressions for $\langle x\rangle (z),
\langle x^2\rangle (z),\Delta x(z),\langle y\rangle (z), \langle y^2\rangle (z)$ and $\Delta y(z)$, where $$\langle x\rangle (z)=\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}x|u(x,y,z)|^2dxdy,$$ and $$\langle x^2\rangle (z)=\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}x^2|u(x,y,z)|^2dxdy,$$ and $$\Delta x(z)=\sqrt{ \langle x^2\rangle (z)-\langle x\rangle (z)^2},$$ and similarly for $y$. I obtained that $\langle x\rangle (z)=0=\langle y\rangle (z)$ and $\langle x^2\rangle (z)=\frac{k_0^2w_0^4+4z^2}{4k_0^2w_0^2}=\langle y^2\rangle (z),$ so $$\Delta x(z)=\frac{\sqrt{4z^2+k_0^2w_0^4}}{2k_0w_0}=\Delta y(z).$$ Now i want to find the physical meaning of these quantities, in fact i should be able describe
how a laser beam diffracts as it propagates through a linear optical medium. Im a pure mathematician so i dont really know the physical interpretation. For me it's just the standard deviation of a bidimensional normal distribution. Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: $w_0$ is the initial waist (circular width) of the beam and if $z \gg k_0w_0^2$ then $\Delta x(z)= \Delta y(z) \approx w_0\frac{z}{k_0w_0^2} $ meaning that the waist is linearly increasing with the propagation distance, the beam gets fatter as it diffracts from its narrower starting state.

Comment: But what's the meaning of $\Delta x$? It seems that you say that its something related to the speed of propagation of the wave?

Comment: plot the function $exp[-\tfrac{x^2+y^2}{w_0^2}]$, it has a bell shape, its rms width at $z=0$ is $w_0$ as you have calculated it. That rms width increases as $z$ increases to $\infty$, the beam spreads out, it diffracts.

Comment: yeah but why this info is codified by $\Delta x$?

Comment: Because the shape of the beam stays constant as it propagates and its size is defined by the rms $\Delta (x) = \Delta y(z)$

Comment: okay thank you very much!